# Python reading file adds extra characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file with some passwords. The problem is when Python prints these passwords or saves them in a variable it adds a random "Â" to the mix and I'm trying to figure out why. I could just replace the "Â" with nothing but I would like to know why this is happening.

```
Some examples:

^oqi£"HS prints out ^oqiÂ£"HS
rS£g)5Q% prints out rSÂ£g)5Q%

Code:

with open('pass.txt') as f:
    first_line = f.readline().rstrip()
    print(first_line)
```

Comment: you should add the code that you're using to read the file.

Comment: And the code printing/manipulating it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [How to make a Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) page. In short, you need to provide 1) the smallest amount of code that reproduces your problems, 2) a concise file with data that reproduces the example, and 3) the exact steps you took to reproduce the problem. The first step any of us will do is copy/paste your code into our local environment and attempt to duplicate the problem, and we can't do that very well if there's no code to copy/paste ;)

Comment: I edited the question, put the code I'm using

Comment: You need to open the file with the same encoding as was used to save it - looks like utf-8 vs. latin-1.

Comment: Try to enforce the encoding and the opening mode `open('pass.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8')`